# Symfony Authentication with own Oauth2 login

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, oauth, authorization

Currently we are using Symfony FOS User Bundle to manage users on our website. I have had finished to implement an AuthService which is an independent service and based on OAuth2. The new AuthService have a different database for user credentials, and on registration it's sending the username, email, and new ID to the old Symfony platform to take it into the database. I fully adapt the Symfony password encryption, so I can import the old users to the AuthService.

The problem: I read a lot about the FOS User Bundle, but I still haven't idea, how can I authenticate the users in Symfony. The flow in the AuthService: The login form is on the website as an iframe and it redirect to symfony_site.com/login_callback with authorizatio code. This send the authorizatio code back to AuthService and get access_token, refresh_token and id of the user after login. But it's not mean that the user logged in on Symfony side. What should I write (I mean on Symfony side for instance: Auth Provider) to login this user?

I tryed to replace it in the security.yml, but I haven't idea what paramters it is waiting fo return back for successfully login. How is this flow are working?